# theme function not available, not called?

Tags: theming

I am extending a module, I want to create a new theme function for the output but it somehow is not recognized. I know of theme registry and rebuild it (manually and via devel module)

The issue is tracked down to

```
function cmis_browser_content_properties() {
    $output = theme('cmis_browser_content_properties', array('cmis_object' => $object));
    debug($output, 'output');
    return $output;
}


function theme_cmis_browser_content_properties($variables) {
  // do sth
  $output = 'sth';
  return $output;
}
```

When I create a new function by copying the existing to

```
function theme_cmis_browser_content_propertiesnewtest($variables)
```

and call it in above module code. There is no output anymore, debug says: ''

```
$output = theme('cmis_browser_content_propertiesnewtest', array('cmis_object' => $object));
```

Please enlighten me!

just fyi the cmis module is a connector to alfresco document repository via CMIS http://drupal.org/project/cmis

just seeing similar questions suggested. Will see if one fits, but send this anyaway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it you've forgotten to register your theme function with the system using [`hook_theme()`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Ffunction%2Fhook_theme%2F7&ei=9armUNWYIcOx0AWB9YGAAg&usg=AFQjCNEDlSDoM9F-Uy1bEpFvPaCtxyN4rA&sig2=FMsov3iPV3JVYmJFJpXSSA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k)

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'cmis_browser_content_propertiesnewtest' => array(
      'variables' => array('cmis_object' => NULL)
    )
  );
}
```

After you clear the caches your theme function should be registered with the system and start working as expected.

Comment: okay that hook implementation was existing in the main module file. So I added my function